# Probability that a randomly chosen eldest child is from a one-child family; a four-child family

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The probability of having a one-child family is $0.1$; the probability of having a two child family is $0.25$; the probability of having a three- child family is $0.35$ and the probability of having a four-child family is $0.3$. If a randomly chosen child is the eldest child in his/her family, calculate the probability that he/she is from:

(a) a one-child family;

(b) a four-child family

my thoughts for part a) 0.1/10 = 0.01 or 1% and for part b) 0.3/10=0.03 or 3%. Unless I am missing something here...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: The answers are 10% and 30%. Now what? Nobody will give you any points for the answer. It’s the _why_ that counts.

Comment: @gnasher729 The "answers" are wrong.

Comment: Excuse me I am new here... but tnx for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes' rule, where $e$ represents "eldest is chosen":

$$P(1|e) = \frac{P(e|1)P(1)}{P(e)}
= \frac{P(e|1)P(1)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 P(e|i)P(i)} \\
= \frac{1 \cdot 0.1}{0.1 \cdot 1 + 0.25 \cdot 1/2 + 0.35 \cdot 1/3 + 0.3 \cdot 1/4} \\
= \frac{0.1}{0.416667} = 0.24 .$$

Comment: So for a four child family then 0.3/0.416667 = 0.72. ?

Comment: @Thomas V:  No it would not.  You're forgetting that if there are four children the probability you choose the eldest is $P(e|4) = 1/4$.

Comment: is it then the top part 1/4 * 0.3 where the bottom part remains the same? therefore, the final result is 0.17.   ? & thank you Sir for your help as all this is new to me...

Comment: Ummm... we call it the "numerator"... but *yes*.